# how to move image on mainwindow inside popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Added a popup on main window , and inside popup added a user control, user control has different controls,

one of the control's is image. i want to move that image on main window.

popup's AllowsTransparency="True"

added preview events in user control code behind. but the movement is absolutely wrong, image is hiding/moving to some where.

events are as below:

```
private void image_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ismove = true;

        if (MouseButtonState.Pressed == e.LeftButton)
        {
            position = Mouse.GetPosition(image);
       }
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void image_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ismove) return;
       if (MouseButtonState.Pressed == e.LeftButton)
        {
            var point = e.GetPosition(null);
            this.image.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(position.X + point.X, position.Y + point.Y);
        }
    }

    private void image_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        ismove = false;
    }
```

Comment: are you mixig relative and absolute coordnates?

Comment: You haven't posted enough information for us to help you. Please also post relevant parts of your XAML. I'm having a hard time understanding why you would be dragging around an image inside a Popup.

Comment: on mainwindow i have large model , need to zoom , pan, rotate and walk in to that model.  mainwindow consists of top appbar and down app bar, each app button(toggle buttons) displays one user control on main window , one of the user control consists of image, need to move that image on mainwindow, my problem is image is not following its mouse movement.

Comment: <Popup x:Name="WalkUCPopUp" AllowsTransparency="True" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=grd3DModel}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grd3DModel}" IsOpen="True"  StaysOpen="True"   Placement="AbsolutePoint"  PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainView}">
                                <local:WalkUC Height="300" Width="300" Margin="0,0,0,-210"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Visibility="visible"/>
                    </Popup> this walkuc consists of image.